# string to 2d float array in golang

Tags: arrays, string, go, floating-point

I am writing a code in go to retrieve data through the rest API. The output I am getting is a two-dimensional array as a string, like this

```
[
[1514771940,13345.7,13381.01,13381,13345.7,4.276442830000001],
[1514771880,13332.12,13387.72,13332.12,13381,14.83685867],
.
.
.
]
```

How can I transform this `string` to 2-D float array?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/text/tabwriter/

Comment: My bad I think I emphasized wrong part of the question, let me edit it.

Comment: Are you sure that’s not just json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an array of arrays in json. You can parse it using the [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    input := `[[1514771940,13345.7,13381.01,13381,13345.7,4.276442830000001],[1514771880,13332.12,13387.72,13332.12,13381,14.83685867]]`

    var parsed [][]float64
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &parsed); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(parsed)
}
```

Prints:

```
[[1.51477194e+09 13345.7 13381.01 13381 13345.7 4.276442830000001] [1.51477188e+09 13332.12 13387.72 13332.12 13381 14.83685867]]
```

You should check the API docs, they must mention what format the response is in. If this is over http, the content-type will tell you as well.